# vb.net, how to set different text colors in data table

Tags: vb.net

I am using vb.net in my project. I have a datagridview bounded to a datatable m_table which has a column called Price_Change with decimal values. I want to display text in datagridview in green if price change>0 and red otherwise. I cannot simply use the following formatting because the bounded data table m_table is constructed in my code, not directly through data base.

```
 DataGridView.Rows(0)Cells(0).Style.ForeColor=COLOR.BLACK
```

Code looks like

```
Dim rowText As DataRow = m_table.NewRow
rowText("Price Change")=10.00 'assign values to price change column

' there is no color formating for data table
```

I wonder if cellformatting event can be used for this purpose. Would it slow down the load of datagridview? Here is a [link] 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub DGVTable_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DGVTable.CellFormatting
    If Me.DGVTable.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = columnPriceChange Then
        If e.Value IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim change As Decimal = CType(e.Value, Decimal)
            If change >= 0 Then
                e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green
            Else
                e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```